# How to generate a continuous string?

Tags: python, string, generator, brute-force, alphanumeric

I want to generate, in python (without a dictionary), a list of string from aaa-zzz and then output a txtfile such as this (note, the ... is short for the strings in between):

```
aaa
aab
aac
aad
...
aaz
aba
abb
abc
abd
...
aaz
...
zaa
...
zzy
zzz
```

The harder challenge is to genrate alternating (upper and lower) strings. How to generate these?

```
aaa
...
aaz
aaA
...
aaZ
aba
...
abz
...
abA
...
abZ
aBa
...
aBz
aBA
...
aBZ
...
zzz
zzA
...
...
zzZ
zAa
...
zAz
...
zZa
...
zZz
...
...
ZZZ
```

Just a bonus question, is there a way to not only include a-z, A-Z but also 0-9 in the generation??

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Does order matter to you in any way?

Comment: order doesn't matter because i could sort it easily if necessary. ecatmur's solution was super elegant!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
import itertools, string

map(''.join, itertools.product(string.ascii_lowercase, repeat=3))
map(''.join, itertools.product(string.ascii_letters, repeat=3))
map(''.join, itertools.product(string.ascii_letters + string.digits, repeat=3))
```

Comment: I spent too long looking for `string.ascii_letters` :).  Very nice indeed.

Comment: Could combine the `join` with a write to file in the map function to meet the OP's requirements, but yes, nice.

Comment: Just redirect the output. :-)